# How do I parse text with multiple sections that have list items with TTP?

Tags: python, parsing, text, text-parsing

I have some text input that looks like:

```
**Section 1**
Description1
1. Foo
2. Bar

**Section 2**
Description2
1. NotFoo
2. NotBar
3. NotFooBar
```

Currently, I have a template that looks like:

```
section1Template = """
<group name = "Section1">
1. {{ item1 | ORPHRASE }}
</group>
"""

section2Template = """
<group name = "Section2">
1. {{ item2 | ORPHRASE }}
</group>
"""

combinedTemplate = f"""
{section1Template}
{section2Template}
"""
```

The expected output:

```
[
    {
        'section1': [{'item1': 'Foo', 'item1': 'Bar'}],
        'section2': [{'item2': 'NotFoo', 'item2': 'NotBar', 'item2': 'NotFooBar'}]
    }
]
```

However, the output I get instead is:

```
[
    {
        'section1': [{'item1': 'Foo', 'item1': 'Bar', 'item1': 'NotFoo', 'item1': 'NotBar', 'item1': 'NotFooBar'}],
        'section2': [{{'item2': 'Foo', 'item2': 'Bar', 'item2': 'NotFoo', 'item2': 'NotBar', 'item2': 'NotFooBar'}]
    }
]
```

How can I fix this template so that I receive the expected output? Each section could have any number of list items as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this template:

```
<group name="{{ section }}">
**{{ section | PHRASE }}**
<group>
{{ item }}. {{ value }}
</group>
</group>
```

on your data using https://textfsm.nornir.tech/ it produces this output:

```
[
    {
        "Section 1": [
            {
                "item": "1",
                "value": "Foo"
            },
            {
                "item": "2",
                "value": "Bar"
            }
        ],
        "Section 2": [
            {
                "item": "1",
                "value": "NotFoo"
            },
            {
                "item": "2",
                "value": "NotBar"
            },
            {
                "item": "3",
                "value": "NotFooBar"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Hope that helps.